# Multiple <input>s with same CSS class updated instead of one specific

Tags: javascript, input, listener

**Intro**
Implementing calendar component in `JS`.

**Use case:**
**1.** User clicks on input,calendar is invoked
**2.** User selects date
**3.** Calendar is closed and Date goes to specific input
**Problem:**
Same Date goes to both inputs

**Code:**
There are two similar(that is requirement) inputs on the page:

```
<input class="date"/>
<input class="date"/>
```

Listeners bound on these inputs this way:

```
<body onload="FlipCalendar.placeholder('date')"/>
```

`elems[i]` is this `<input>`,that's passed thru functions(in that order):

**1.** `var placeholder = function(className){...}`
**2.** `var dateInit = function(calInvoker){...}`
 
**3.** `var selectDay = function(day,calInvoker){...}`

**Question and Expectations:**
The question is why **both** `<input>`s updated,when calendar for specific **one** is invoked?
I assume,that reference to `elems[i]` is unique,but it happened,that it's referred to all `<input>`s on the page.
**Demo:**
**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NvdsU/2/)**

**P.S.** 
Sorry for lot of unstructured code in my demo.
**3** functions that I mentioned above are really relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/safes/)

`t.addEventListener` is replaced with `t.onclick`.

Comment: nice! working perfect.Interesting why `addEventListener` didn't work for this case?

Comment: I tried to stop propagation and bubbling but found we can't get if event listener is attached using `addEventListener`. `onlcick` just worked fine.